# In Excel, cell A1 contains a date 20-Oct-2023. In cell A2, how to check if A1 is the 20 day of the month?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, cell A1 contains a date 20-Oct-2023.  In cell A2, how to check if A1 is the 20 day of the month?

Comment: Try `=DAY(A1)=20`

Answer (score 0):

Use `DAY()` function

```
=DAY(A1)=20
```